# Multipying int64 types in OCAML

Tags: ocaml

I am attempting to multiply two int types in OCAML and I am not sure on what I might be doing wrong

```
   let  prime        =   Int64.of_string("0x100000002b2") in
   let  temp         =   ref prime in
   hash := Int64.mul(!temp,prime);
```

I get the error

```
Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b
       but an expression was expected of type int64
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this ?

**Update:**

I got reference to this method from [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Int64.html)

I am curious what this means

```
val mul : int64 -> int64 -> int64
Multiplication.
```

How do we know how many parameters this method takes ?

Comment: Free yourself of C/Java: You do not need brackets in OCaml for function calls. Just write "Int64.mul a b" not "Int64.mul (a, b)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters in OCaml are (in the usual idiom) placed after the name of the function, with no parentheses and no comma.

```
# Int64.mul 8L 9L;;
- : int64 = 72L
```

Commas are used to create tuples, but `Int64.mul` doesn't accept a tuple. It accepts two separate arguments as above. (In FP parlance, it's a curried function.)

(It might be worth working through a short tutorial on OCaml. You seem to be assuming it's like traditional C family languages, but it's rather different.)

**Update**

The type `x -> y` is the type of a function that accepts a parameter of type `x` and returns a value of type `y`. The type `x -> y -> z` is the type of a (curried) function that takes two parameters of types `x` and `y` and returns a value of type `z`. (This is a somewhat simplified way of looking at things, but is close enough to get started with.)

So the function `mul` that you cite takes two parameters of type `int64` and returns a value of type `int64`.

(I repeat my advice about an OCaml tutorial. It's really worth learning about the OCaml type system before getting too deep into coding.)

Comment: thanks that did the trick could you also please answer my updated question. I am not sure regarding the docs

Comment: It sure is. It is very different from C. I am following various online resources.

Comment: It's not only the C family of languages. For example, the syntax of calling functions in Standard ML is identical to that in OCaml. But most standard library functions in Standard ML are uncurried (they take a tuple), for which the OP's usage would be correct. They could have been written to be curried; they just aren't. So the convention the library uses is also a factor.

Comment: Very true, good point. OP was asking about comparison of integer types in OCaml to C++ in a different SO question, which is why I mentioned the C family. But many languages use parens and commas.